# adding string in others

Tags: python

I have a string like `script = "C:\Users\dell\byteyears.py"`. I wanna put the string `"Python27\"` in between the string like `script = "C:\Users\dell\Python27\byteyears.py`. Why I need is because build_scripts is not running correctly on the windows. Anyway, how can I do this wish in time efficient way ?

EDIT : I will not print anything. String is stored on the script variable  in the build_scripts

```
  script = convert_path(script)
```

I should put something to convert it, like

```
  script = convert_path(script.something("Python27/"))
```

The question is that what `something` should be.

Comment: it depends how script looks like... what is script? a plain string?

Comment: @Torxed it seems it is plain string

Comment: Check my latest update/solution, using the replacea method and making sure that your path is SYSTEM valid via `abspath()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path` is best for dealing with paths, also forward slashes are ok to use in Python.

```
In [714]: script = r"C:/Users/dell/byteyears.py"
In [715]: head, tail = os.path.split(script)
In [716]: os.path.join(head, 'Python27', tail)
Out[716]: 'C:/Users/dell/Python27/byteyears.py'
```

in a module.

```
import os
script = r"C:/Users/dell/byteyears.py"
head, tail = os.path.split(script)
newpath = os.path.join(head, 'Python27', tail)
print newpath
```

gives

```
'C:/Users/dell/Python27/byteyears.py'
```

internally Python is in general agnostic about the slashes, so use forward slashes "/" as they look nicer and save having to escape.

Comment: how can I use your code in the module ? what is the meaning of the In [], Out [] ?

Comment: I was using iPython and they're just the markers. I'll edit to make sense.

Comment: Again, this is just for adding trailing pats, not in the middle really :)

Comment: I produced what the OP wanted which was easy enough as they wanted in effect to append a directory name on to the existing directory. I think using ``os.path.*`` is more explicit in the simple case. I accept that if the path was really really deep then using ``os.path.split`` would be torture. Usually I find that it's a matter of changing the head or tail of a directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.path.join(script[:script.rfind('\\')],'Python27',script[script.rfind('\\'):])
```

Comment: Just a note: This will only work on paths where you want to add `Python27\\ ` at the end of the path, not in the middle.
Likewise, mine only works if `\\dell` is present in the path.

To be truly dynamic choose the last solution i wrote.

Comment: your solution is finding first occurance of the \. The result is 'C:\Python27\byteyears.py' not 'C:\Users\Dell\Python27\byteyears.py'

Comment: First, its not searching for `Dell` anywhere; second its searching form the right (that's the `r` in `rfind`), so it will find the _last_ `\\`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Dunno if you commented mainly on my comment or the users, i was reffering to MY solution not yours in my comment.. i just gave a heads up that this will only work on adding additional path data trailing on the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from os.path import abspath
script = "C:\\Users\\dell\\byteyears.py"
script = abspath(script.replace('dell\\', 'dell\\Python27\\'))
```

### **Note:** Never forget to escape \ when working with strings!

And if you're mixing / and \ then you'd better use abspath() to correct it to your platform!

---

Other ways:

```
print "C:\\Users\\dell\\%s\\byteyears.py" % "Python27"
```

or if you want the path to be more dynamic, this way you can pass a empty string:

```
print "C:\\Users\\dell%s\\byeyears.py" % "\\Python27"
```

Also possible:

```
x = "C:\\Users\\dell%s\\byeyears.py"
print x
x = x % "\\Python27"
print x
```

Comment: In real-run- time, I donot know what the script variable is holding. So, I could not find a way to use your solution

Comment: You have to know what the `script` variable contains at run-time otherwise you can't mess around and add `Python27` in the middle of the string, you would have to know if the string has to bee added at the start, end or in-between (as you stated in your question) :)
To be able to help you further I for one, would need to have at least 3 different examples of how and where you want to add the `Python27` string, so we can corelate that and build a suitable regexp lookup or replacement function.

Comment: Using ``x = r"C:\Users\dell%s\byeyears.py"`` will negate the need for the escaping.

Comment: @sotapme Try the following, and you'll see that it doesn't in most Python versions `p = r'C:\somewhere\%the\rainbow\fiel.py' % r'over'` or at least this doesn't work for me..